# (True of False) $X,Y$ are discrete random variables

Tags: probability

> With $P(x=1)>0$ and $P(x=2)>0$. Suppose $P(y=1\mid x=1)=3/4$ and $P(y=2\mid x=2)=3/4$. Then $X$ and $Y$ cannot be independent.

My idea is to suppose it's independent, then $P(Y\cap X)=P(X)P(Y)$ and thus cancel with the denominator, then $P(Y_1)=P(Y_2)=3/4$, which is impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\mathbb P(Y = 1 | X=1)$ does not depend on the condition $X=1$, then we should have $\mathbb P(Y=1 | X=1) = \mathbb P(Y=1) = 3/4$ and similarly $\mathbb P(Y=2 | X=2) = \mathbb P(Y=2) = 3/4$. But then $\mathbb P(Y \in \{ 1,2 \}) = \mathbb P(Y=1) + \mathbb P(Y=2) = 3/4 + 3/4 = 3/2$, contradicting the fact that $\mathbb P$ is a probability because probabilities are in the interval $[0,1]$.

You were on the right track with your $\mathbb P(Y \cap X) = \mathbb P(Y) \mathbb P(X)$ thing but watch out; you must compute probability of *events* (such as $\{ Y=1 \}$ or $\{Y \le 0 \}$) and not of variables (such as $\mathbb P(Y)$, which doesn't make sense). That is probably where you got stuck, I assume. It doesn't make sense to "intersect variables", but intersecting events (which are sets) makes sense. Note that $\mathbb P(A \cap B) = \mathbb P(A) \mathbb P(B)$ is equivalent to 
$$
\mathbb P( A | B) = \frac{\mathbb P( A \cap B ) }{\mathbb P(B)} = \mathbb P(A).
$$
Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks! so if I say $P(Y=1)P(X=1) \over P(X=1)$ then the assumption would be correct?

Comment: @Roy Wang : About which assumption are you talking about?